# Xamarin Forms - coding separate UI for iPhone and iPad

Tags: c#, ios, ipad, xamarin.forms

I am working on an existing `Xamarin` app and all UI is C# using `Xamarin` Forms.  The app is for `Android` and `iOS` platforms and I am now tasked with adding support for the `iPad`.

It isn't practical to have one scaleable `UI` for both platforms as we would like to utilise the extra screen real-estate with a better experience for the user.

My question is, how in code do I determine if the UI is iOS and specifically the iPad and display something different.  Is there simply conditional logic I could put in a IF statement to draw the alternatives?

Comment: just example  FontSize = ((Device.Idiom == TargetIdiom.Phone) ? 12 : (Device.Idiom == TargetIdiom.Tablet) ? 16 : 16);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the `Device` class does the trick:

```
if (Device.OS == TargetPlatform.iOS && Device.Idiom == TargetIdiom.Tablet)
```